# Time Zone issue in Azure Function app with consumption plan (Windows)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-app-service-plans

I'm using a Function App in consumption plan (Windows) to execute a C# function, but when the  line of code `DateTime.Now` is executed the time it returns UTC. I already have changed the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` in the app settings to `SA Pacific Standard Time` based on [the default time zones](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/default-time-zones) but it doesn't work.

I also did a test on the development tools console with the time command, but the result of the console does correspond to the expected time, contrary to the `DateTime.Now` statement whose result is in UTC.

[image]

Comment: Why not use UTC (`DateTime.UtcNow`) and then use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` to put it in a specific time zone?

Answer (score 0):

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp66
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation(DateTime.UTCNow.ToString());
            return new OkObjectResult("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```

After set the `WEBSITE_TIME_ZONE` to `SA Pacific Standard Time` and deploy, my code works fine on azure:

[image]

console also no problem:

[image]

So your code should be no problem, you can try below things:

1, restart the function app to let the function app re-load the environment variable, and then try again.

2, try other GMT-5 TIMEZONE, from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-vista/cc749073(v=ws.10)#time-zones), they are:

`SA Pacific Standard Time`

`Eastern Standard Time`

`US Eastern Standard Time`

3, convert the TIMEZONE manually in your code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace FunctionApp66
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var date = System.TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(DateTime.UtcNow, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("SA Pacific Standard Time"));
            log.LogInformation(date.ToString());
            return new OkObjectResult("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }
}
```